# Multiprocess by Using Android NDK SharedMemory.h

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, ipc, shared-memory

I keep trying Multi Processing (using Shared Memory) in Android Studio (With NDK). I installed NDK, LLDB, CMake. Also I use API Level 26 and min SDK is also 26 (OREO, 8.0).

I created native_lib.cpp, and making some files for testing FD.

I made simple small class for testing .

Class has `int FileDescriptor, char* buffer.`

I checked variables and it seems like made succesfully. `ASharedMemory_Create() returns fd`, and i can get size of memory from `ASharedMemory_getSize(int fd)`.

But how can i access shared memory from another process? Am i need to use java for IPC? If i can i want to use native only. Currently java is only for UI.

https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/memory

I checekd here. If there are something that worth i can refer please let me know. Thank you.

**Edited---------------------------------------------------**

I want to make shared memory in both of parent and child. Also want to access shared memory freely. Child to child, child to parents, parents to child.

Making File Descriptor and buffer in parents works smoothly, but when i try to make buffer or fd in child, i cant access it.

I used same name and size for `ASharedMemory_create`, but other process making different File descriptor in my opinion. Don't know whats wrong.

Below is my `native_lib.cpp` for testing. Functions matched with Buttons except `Init`. `Init` called `onCreate.`

```
int fd[4];
char* buffer[4];

int myFd;
int* cBuf;

const char* names[4] = {"Test", "Inter", "Process", "Mech"};
const int size = 512;

extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_org_techtwon_multipro_MainActivity_SyncBuffer(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    int cVal;
    memcpy(&cVal, cBuf, sizeof(int));

    for(int i = 0 ; i < cVal; ++i)
    {
        if(fd[i] != NULL) {
            buffer[i] = (char *) mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd[i], 0);
        }
    }
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_org_techtwon_multipro_MainActivity_MakeFileDesc(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */) {

    pid_t pid = fork();
    int cVal;

    if(pid < 0) {
        return;
    } else if(pid == 0) {
        memcpy(&cVal, cBuf, sizeof(int));

        fd[cVal] = ASharedMemory_create(names[cVal], size);
        buffer[cVal] = (char*) mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd[cVal], 0);

        memset(buffer[cVal], 0, size);
        memcpy(buffer[cVal], names[cVal], strlen(names[cVal]));

        cVal++;
        memcpy(cBuf, &cVal, sizeof(int));

        sleep(1);
        exit(1);
    }
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_org_techtwon_multipro_MainActivity_Init(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    myFd = ASharedMemory_create("Num", sizeof(int));
    cBuf = (int*) mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_SHARED, myFd, 0);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 4; ++i) fd[i] = ASharedMemory_create(names[i], size);

    buffer[0] = (char*) mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_SHARED, fd[0], 0);
    memcpy(buffer[0], names[0], strlen(names[0]));

    memset(cBuf, 0, sizeof(int));
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_org_techtwon_multipro_MainActivity_GetFd(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */, jint idx) {
    return fd[idx];
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL
Java_org_techtwon_multipro_MainActivity_GetBuffer(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */, jint idx) {

    jbyteArray tmp = (*env).NewByteArray(strlen(buffer[idx]));

    env->SetByteArrayRegion(tmp, 0, strlen(buffer[idx]), (jbyte*) buffer[idx]);

    return tmp;
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_org_techtwon_multipro_MainActivity_GetcVal(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */, jint idx) {

    int cVal;
    memcpy(&cVal, cBuf, sizeof(int));

    return cVal;
}
```

Comment: so did you call `mmap` after calling `ASharedMemory_Create` ("The resulting file descriptor can be mmap'ed to process memory space  ,,,")?

Comment: @pskink Yeah, `buffer = (char*) mmap(NULL, ASharedMemory_getSize(fd), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)` is what i did it.

Comment: good, now use your `buffer`

Comment: @pskink I used it and works it. I was confused :( Thank you for answer. But If I want to access to shared memory created by child process, how can i access it? is there any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code snippet in [official docs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/memory.html#group___memory_1ga73942d1bb873cb4b73b8b92c30c778ef) has it quite clear:

```
int fd = ASharedMemory_create("memory", 128);

// By default it has PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC.
char *buffer = (char *) mmap(NULL, 128, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

strcpy(buffer, "This is an example."); // trivially initialize content

// limit access to read only
ASharedMemory_setProt(fd, PROT_READ);

// share fd with another process here and the other process can only map with PROT_READ.
```

The *name* has no meaning, only helpful for debugging. The *size* should match.

This is the API you [should use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53058077/multiprocess-by-using-android-ndk-sharedmemory-h#comment105859897_53062250) for API 29 and higher, the old ways (below) [don't work anymore](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-10#shared-memory).

If you need also to cover devices below API 26, you need a *fallback* that makes direct IOCTLs to `/dev/ashmem` file descriptors. This was available since Android early days:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/ashmem.h>

int fd = open("/dev/ashmem", O_RDWR);

ioctl(fd, ASHMEM_SET_NAME, "memory");
ioctl(fd, ASHMEM_SET_SIZE, 128);

char *buffer = (char * ) mmap(NULL, 128, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

There even is a nice example of wrapping this shared memory for use in Java: *[ANDROID – CREATING SHARED MEMORY USING ASHMEM](http://devarea.com/android-creating-shared-memory-using-ashmem)*.

Comment: Thank you for answer. It works smoothly. But i can't access through `AsharedMemory_create` even name and size matches. I tried 2 ways to access to shared memory, But both failed. (**First** : make fd from parents, try to make buffer from child) (**Second** : define fd and buffer as null in parents, try to make both of them from child) can i know why? or Is there any other way to access to shared memory maked by child?

Comment: Also it doesn't matter min sdk version to me. That's why i used Sharedmem.h. I should've specify in context. Sorry :(

Comment: It's OK that you are OK with API 26, I added the workaround for completeness, caring about others here on SO who cold care.

Comment: Seriously, I know it looks like code monkey but I can't why it doesn't work at all. I understand what you said and offical docs, and that is exactly how i programmed in my view. but i can't access from parents to SharedMemory which made by child. When i check in child process, `File Descriptor` maded, `buffer(sharedMemory)` assigned. I can write some data to there in child. It works fine as i expected. But after exit from child or not, i can't access from parents to child at all. I tried `msync` too but doesn't work too.

Comment: Whatever, Thank you for answer kindly. It really inspired me. Maybe i need to find other way like what you linked.

Comment: Truly sorry about ask again, But i searched so much time.. But i can't how can it works what you said. I mean **Don't need to pass Fd** part. Is there something that i miss? I planning to making SharedMemory between some processes in **same application**. Combine some service(different process) and activities. But all i found is that i need to use Unix Domain Socket for pass File Descriptor. Am i wrong?

Comment: I called `ASharedMemory_create` using by same name and size in both processes (service and activity, parents and child, and so on) and mmap for use that fd. But it didn't reference same memory. Actually, It makes **Shared Memory**, But not for each other. When i mmap File Descriptor that created before `fork()` (so shared with parents and child) it works perfectly. Also It doesn't matter about `close(fd)` or `munmap()`. in my experience. I checked all of them but nothing changed at all..

Comment: Sorry, this was my mistake. fork or pipe or ParcelFileDescriptor (via Binder) is necessary.

Comment: Big thanks to [Mehmet Ali Meram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10894086/mehmet-ali-meram) for an update about the [new restrictions on direct use of IOCTLs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-10#shared-memory) in API 29.

Comment: @AlexCohn: Is there any way to share memory between sdk and ndk below api-26? [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60055133/shared-memory-between-ndk-and-sdk-below-api-level-26) is my post, looking for your feedback.

Comment: @TruthSeeker note that this discussion is not relevant to your question. The words **shared memory** have two very different meanings (both legitimate): sharing memory across processes (as here) and sharing memory between managed and unmanaged code (as there). I have written an answer for your question.

Comment: @AlexCohn: yes,  Current discussion is not what i was looking for but I couldn't find relevant channel to contact you. I'll delete the comment. Sorry.

Comment: @TruthSeeker that's not a problem, you can keep it 

Comment: @AlexCohn Another option for sharing shmem file descriptor with another process is using sendmsg/recvmsg (as suggested by [docs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/memory)). See [this repo](https://github.com/pelya/android-shmem) for example code.